# InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype bool ... [[accuracy/accuracy_var/_3191]]

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, pre-trained-model

I have trained a Model of Squeeze and excitation Convolutional Neural Network with MNIST DataSet. I have saved the Trained Model in a folder.

For using the trained model in production, I have restored it and tried to predict on new data but I am getting the following error message.

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must
>   feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype bool
>          [[{{node Placeholder}}]]
>          [[accuracy/accuracy_var/_3191]]

Model Restore Code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from cifar10 import *

init_learning_rate = 0.1
train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y = prepare_data()
train_x, test_x = color_preprocessing(train_x, test_x)
tf.reset_default_graph()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("./model/ResNeXt.ckpt.meta")

with tf.Session() as sess:
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state('./model')
    if ckpt and tf.train.checkpoint_exists(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path):
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()

        for n in graph.as_graph_def().node:
            print(n.name)

        cost = graph.get_tensor_by_name("cost_reduce_mean:0")
        accuracy = graph.get_tensor_by_name("accuracy/accuracy_var:0")

        test_batch_x = test_x[0: 1000]
        test_batch_y = test_y[0: 1000]

        x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("placeholder_x_input:0")
        label = graph.get_tensor_by_name("placeholder_label_input:0")

        training_flag = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='tr_fg_99999')
        learning_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='learning_rate_99999')

        test_feed_dict = {x: test_batch_x,label: test_batch_y,learning_rate: 0.1,training_flag: False}
        loss_, acc_ = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict=test_feed_dict)
        total_acc = acc_
```

Once the line - `loss_, acc_ = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict=test_feed_dict)` executes, it gives the error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1320, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1408, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype bool
  [[{{node Placeholder}}]]
  [[accuracy/accuracy_var/_3191]]

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2411, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1802, in run
    launch(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.6\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)

Comment: File "C:/Self/ImageRecognition/HandWDigitsRecognition/LoadModel.py", line 40, in <module>
    loss_, acc_ = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict=test_feed_dict)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 930, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1153, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1329, in _do_run
    run_metadata)

Comment: File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1349, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype bool
  [[node Placeholder (defined at /Self/ImageRecognition/HandWDigitsRecognition/LoadModel.py:8) ]]
  [[accuracy/accuracy_var/_3191]]

Comment: @Matt, I could not format the stack trace properly as code tag not working properly on comments, as it is a second class citizen.

Comment: I need to see how the model is constructed. The inputs you are giving the model are not the ones that the model accepts or are not in the proper order

Comment: @IgnacioPeletier, thank you for your quick reply! In this comment section I can not format the code properly, so i am going to email that to you. Would you please check your email.

Comment: Hi, try to remove the lines where you define cost and accuracy, those tensors are already defined inside the graph and there is no need to get them by their name.

Comment: @IgnacioPeletier, Thank you for your reply. I Just tried by removing those two line, But the line - "loss_, acc_ = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict=test_feed_dict)", required to pass those two tensor. Where will I get those? Please describe a bit more in details.

Comment: Are you sure the tensor names that you get by name are correct? Tensorflow does funny things with the names. Check to loop throught the tensor nanmes with [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]

Comment: @IgnacioPeletier, Yes I already checked that one, like below-

for n in graph.as_graph_def().node:
            print(n.name)

Those two tensor name is there.

Comment: But are you sure they are the ones you want? It looks like you are inputing types that the tensors you have don't accept. And it is asking you for a boolean in the tensor named 'Placeholder'